# What does this portion of code do? I'm kinda lost

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, att

ive been trying to trace this for awhile now, and  I just cant get it. some background before it, we are asked for a string that has a length of 6 before it, and if does not have it the program will fail. I'm trying to figure out what exact string would pass into the strings not equal test and return a 1.

I've tried to trace it but I can't really get it. I realize that movzbl is moving a byte to edx but then im not sure what happens after that.

```
0x00000000004010d7 <+25>:    movzbl (%rbx,%rax,1),%edx
0x00000000004010db <+29>:    and    $0xf,%edx
0x00000000004010de <+32>:    movzbl 0x4025c0(%rdx),%edx
0x00000000004010e5 <+39>:    mov    %dl,(%rsp,%rax,1)
0x00000000004010e8 <+42>:    add    $0x1,%rax
0x00000000004010ec <+46>:    cmp    $0x6,%rax
0x00000000004010f0 <+50>:    jne    0x4010d7 <test+25>
0x00000000004010f2 <+52>:    movb   $0x0,0x6(%rsp)
0x00000000004010f7 <+57>:    mov    $0x402577,%esi
0x00000000004010fc <+62>:    mov    %rsp,%rdi
0x00000000004010ff <+65>:    callq  0x40132e <strings_not_equal>
0x0000000000401104 <+70>:    test   %eax,%eax
```

// strings not equal returns 1 when strings arent equal but im not sure what strings it compares

Comment: This is a binary bomb lab, right?  `movzbl` is a byte load, `and    $0xf,%edx` is taking the low nibble.  Then it uses that to index another byte from a static array, probably also read-only data judging from the address.  You should look there.

Comment: yeah but what do i do after that? theres just a bunch of hex numbers : 0x4025c0 <array.3156>:  0x7564616d      0x73726569      0x746f666e      0x6c796276

Comment: yes, its just a bunch of raw data.  The code loads a byte from there and then continues on to the next instruction here.

Comment: o ok, but then how do I figure out what string to put in if its just raw data?

Comment: and does the mov %d1, (%rsp, %rax, 1) line do? does that affect anything?

Comment: `dl` is the low byte of EDX.  (So that store is of the lookup result is into an array on the stack.)